# React Native - increase/decrease height of View on click with transition

Tags: react-native

I want to create an Accordion with collapsible items inside it - where each item have different types of content. I cant find any examples on this topic without installing a module. When installing a module each list item will have equal layout something i dont want to have. I've tried with animation values but then i get the error that animated module is not supporting changes in height. How can I implement a transition so whenever i click on a header component a box eases out with different height values regarding its content?

```
export function ListItem() {
let [toggled, setToggled] = useState(false);

return(

      <View>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red", height: 50}} onPress={() => setToggled(prev => !prev)}>
              <Text>
                  Header
              </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Animated.View style={{backgroundColor: "blue", height: toggled ? 100 : 50}}>
                <Text>
                    Content
                </Text>
          </Animated.View>
      </View>

  );
}
```

**toggled = false**

[Image with toggled false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWCk6.png)

**Toggled = true**

[Image with toggled true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qdHk.png)

Comment: both images are the same

Comment: Isn't your code showing any animation only or problem with changing height?

Comment: The problem is that when i click on "header" shown in picture 1 it pops into picture 2 without any smooth transition. How can i achieve a smooth transition between these heights whenever i click on the header.

Answer (score 1):

Do it that way

[example in expo](https://snack.expo.io/@yoel301/brave-cheese)

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, Animated, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default function ListItem() {
  let [toggled, setToggled] = useState(false);
  const height = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(height, {
      toValue: toggled ? 1 : 0,
      duration: 400,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }, [toggled]);

  const saveButtonHeight = height.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [50, 100],
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', height: 50}}
        onPress={() => setToggled((prev) => !prev)}>
        <Text>Header</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Animated.View
        style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', height: saveButtonHeight}}>
        <Text>Content</Text>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! Could you explain why this is a better way?

Comment: I get this error when copy pasting your code:

Error: Style property "height" is not supported by native animated module

Comment: Delete this line       ``useNativeDriver: true``

Answer (score -2):

Using redash and reanimated i figured it out. Collapsible component:

```
export function ListItem() {
let [toggled, setToggled] = useState(false);



const transition = useTransition(toggled, {duration: 200});

const bottomRadius = interpolate(transition, {
    inputRange: [0, 16 / 400],
    outputRange: [0, 0.5]
});

const height = interpolate(transition, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, 100]
});

return(

    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red", height: 50}} onPress={() =>  setToggled(val => !val)}>
            <Text>
                Header
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Animated.View style={[{
            borderBottomLeftRadius: bottomRadius,
            borderBottomRightRadius: bottomRadius,
            height: height, backgroundColor: "pink"},
        ]}>
            <Text>
                Content
            </Text>
        </Animated.View>
    </View>

);
```

}